# Validating dates in Laravel (4.2)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble validating dates in Laravel (4.2)

```
$input = array('date_field' => '23/12/2');
$validation_rules = array('date_field'  => 'required|date_format:d/m/y');
$validation = Validator::make($input, $validation_rules);
echo ($validation->fails()) ? 'fail' : 'pass';
```

with the sample (though incorrect) date being passed 23/12/2, the validator still returns a pass, which technically should be a fail.

I'm basically trying to force the input field format so that it matches the dd/mm/yy UK date format.

Thanks!

Comment: since your date field value and validation format is equal that's why its pass.

Comment: Is this considered a correct date -> 23/12/2 ?? Shouldn't the year figure be at least 2 digits?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `regex:` to ensure the format in addition to `date_format`, for example:

```
$validation_rules = [
    'date_field' => [
        'required',
        'date_format:m/d/y',
        'regex:#[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}#'
    ]
];
```

But `'23/12/2'` is not valid and supposed to be failed but confused why it passed, anyway!

Comment: Thanks for that! Adding the regex rule ensured that the date format is xx/xx/xx. You will still need the date_format rule so that you can;t enter 99/99/99, which would pass under the regex alone.

Comment: Actually `date_format` is *still* required - because it is running against PHP DateFormat - and will check the date itself is *valid* - ie. you cant have 30 Feb etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use after rules in the date. You can specify minimum date user can enter. This way the validation result will be passed if the user enter date after the minimum date.

Example

```
$input = array('date_field' => '23/12/2');
$minDate = '01/01/67';
$validation_rules = array('date_field'  => 'required|date_format:d/m/y|after:' . $minDate);
$validation = Validator::make($input, $validation_rules);
echo ($validation->fails()) ? 'fail' : 'pass';
```

Another solution you must write custom validation to check if the date or month user input more than something.

Example custom validation to verify month

```
Validator::extend('maxMonth', function($field,$value,$parameters){

    $value = explode("/", $value);
    if($value[1] < 13) {
        $value[1] = true;
    }
    else {
        $value[1] = false;
    }
    return $value[1];
});

Route::get('/date', function()
{

    $input = array('date_field' => '33/12/68');

    $validation_rules = array('date_field'  => 'required|date_format:d/m/y|maxMonth');

    $messages = array(
        'maxMonth'=>'Please enter month between 01-12'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $validation_rules, $messages);

    if($validation->passes()){
        // Do something if passes
    }else{
        // Do something if fails
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what the possible date range will be so can't specify a minDate.